# TestNG skipping Tests when a Test can't be instantiated

Tags: java, maven, testng

I understand that TestNG has configFailurePolicy flag to continue tests when there is an error in `@Before` method. But is there a way to continue running remaining tests when one test got errored out.. say some exception during Test class instantiation?

Is it possible to report this as error and fail the build?

Here are my test classes.

```
public class MyTest {

 public MyTest() {
  throw new RuntimeException(); 
 }

 @Test
 public void testMethod1() {
   ...
 }

 @Test
 public void testMethod2() {
   ...
 }
}

public class MyTest2 {

 @Test
 public void testMethod1() {
   ...
 }

 @Test
 public void testMethod2() {
   ...
 }
}
```

Now, I am running these tests via Maven:

```
mvn clean test
```

Output:

```
Running Test Suite
....
Cause by: org.testng.TestNGException
Cannot instantiate class ...MyTest1
....
Cause by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
....

Results:
Tests run: 0, Failed: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
....

--------------
Build Success
--------------
Total time: ..
```

Maven pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>XYZ</name>

        <dependencies>
          ....
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
          <plugins>
            ....
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
           </plugins>
         </build>

         <reporting>
           <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/site</outputDirectory>
           <plugins>
             <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
             </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </reporting>
        </project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file?

Comment: Added pom file in the question.

Comment: Do you have a testng.xml file?

Comment: No I am not using testng.xml file